# Errors during converting Angular 5 project in to Ionic/Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

Inspiring from Medium.com (https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6), I want to convert my Angular 5 web project into Hybrid mobile app. I followed every steps. I merged the Angular files and folders and also merged the package.json into one (under the mobile app folder).

After running the command : `ng serve`
I encountered with the following error:

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null

After running the command: ionic serve -l
I encountered with the following error:

> > Error: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start. It likely that a file referenced does not exist: /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/src/assets/**/*, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/src/index.html, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/src/manifest.json, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/src/service-worker.js, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/***/, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js, /var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js
> >         at new BuildError (/var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
> >         at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/www/html/demoionic1/githubIonic/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/watch.js:71:20)
> >         at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
> >         at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
> >         at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5) hasBeenLogged: false, isFatal: false

The package.json file (under the mobile app folder) is as follows:

```js
{
  "name": "githubIonic",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The original package.json file (under the original Angular web app) is below:

```js
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

How can I fix those above mentioned errors? Where are my mistakes?